# Did Brahma kill any Asuras/Rakshasas tormenting humanity?

Tags: vishnu, brahma, asuras, rakshasa

The Puranas are full of tales of Asuras/Rakshasas who obtain boons from Brahma and trouble humans and Devas only to be killed by Vishnu.  Did Brahma also kill any enemies of humans/Devas?

Comment: He on the contrary stops devatas from killing them